# How to remove delivery address and delivery method in checkout page-opencart2

Tags: php, css, opencart

I want to remove Step 2,Step 3: Billing Details from the Checkout Page of OpenCart 2.0.
I've seen a lot of how-tos but not for OpenCart 2.0.

i tried like that,

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="display:none">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-address">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="display:none">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-method">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: are you using vqmod for this if yes then you need to override both view and controller

Comment: No i'm not using.

Comment: you need to modify both views and controller

Comment: also you need to write custome checkout page or use onepage checkout for this https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=15580

Comment: please answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer on opencart forum...

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=183202

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this .

Just go to

Admin/product/data

and requires shipping select to No.

Also you can by default set shipping to No.